# Deserializing objects from file in java (ObjectInputStream)

Tags: java, stack-overflow

I want to store several steps within my processing chain as object within a binary file.
So I let the object classes implementing the serialize interfaces and wrote the ArrayList of my objects into a binary file using an ObjectOutputStream.
To read the object I used (List) o.readObject()
which works fine for a small test data set.
When I increase the size of the ArrayList and the included objects I get a StackOverflowError by trying to read the object from file system.
As it works fine for a small data set, I'm wondering if it is a scalability issue?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at java.lang.ReflectiveOperationException.<init>(ReflectiveOperationException.java:89)
at java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException.<init>(InvocationTargetException.java:72)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1004)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1872)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1777)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1347)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1970)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1894)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1777)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please post your code, see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Maybe the name of the error prompted this post :)